Does $J(y) = \int_0^1 xy'^2(x) \mathrm{d} x$ have global or local extrema?
Let $X = \left\{ w \in C^1([0,1]) \mid w(0) = 1, w(1) = 0 \right\}$ and define $J\colon X\to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
J(y) = \int_0^1 xy'^2(x) \mathrm{d} x.
$$

(a) Prove that $\inf_{w\in X} J(w)=0$.

It easy to see that $J(y) \geq 0$ for all $y\in X$. However, I think there is no $y\in X$ such that $J(y) = 0$. Indeed, solving the Euler-Lagrange equation I get $y(x) = c \log x + k$ for some constants $c,k$, which is not even defined at $0$, so it does not satisfy the border conditions. Thus the claim is false.

(b) Does $J$ have any global or local extremum?

By the first part, $J$ does not have any global or local minimum since it does not have any critical points (as no extremal satisfy the border conditions).
Is this argument correct? Thanks for your help.

For $(a)$, infimum does not mean minimum. Generally it also seems like you need to use some sort of Lagrange multipliers to take into account the boundary condition. Did you do so?

Similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236580/finding-whether-the-functional-attains-infimum?noredirect=1.

@jd27 You are right, I don't have to prove the infimum is achieved. Using the idea of the question cited by Gonçalo, given $\varepsilon >0$, we  notice $y(x) = 1- x^\epsilon$  belongs to $X$, and $J(y)\leq \int_0^1 |y'(x)|^2\mathrm{d}x\leq \Vert y'\Vert_\infty^2 = \varepsilon$. It follows $\inf_{w\in X} J(w)=0$.

@jd27 I don't understand how Lagrange multipliers can be used in this situation, we don't have an additional constraint, only boundary conditions. Could you elaborate please?

You can add a Lagrange multiplier to constrain the boundary condition but the standard calculus of variations method of handling it is much simpler.

@mticus With regards to the Lagrange multipliers: It is as whpowell says. I was overcomplicating things. With regards to your inf solution: The idea seems right, but i think your estimation does not work since if $0<\varepsilon <1$, then the derivative of $y$ will be unbounded (and $|y^\prime|_\infty$  not equal $\varepsilon$).

To fix your argument in the comments, let $y(x) = 1-x^\epsilon$, then $y' = \varepsilon x^{\varepsilon-1}$. The objective is then
$$
\int_0^1xy'(x)^2~\mathrm{d}x = \varepsilon^2\int_0^1 x^{2\varepsilon-1}~\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\varepsilon^2}{2\varepsilon} = \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.
$$
Hence the infimum is $0$.
